# handlebar partials not fully showing up in layout

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

I'm having trouble getting the `locations` data showing up on my final HTML output.  What happens is that all the HTML outside the `{{#each}}` block of weather2.handleblocks show up fine, but everything within the block do not show.
Here's the data that I want showing up on my main layout. I wrapped the data with a function  that is defined in my application file.

```
function getWeatherData(){
    return {
        locations: [
        {
        name: 'Portland',
        forecastUrl: 'http://www.wunderground.com/US/OR/Portland.html',
        iconUrl: 'http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/cloudy.gif',
        weather: 'Overcast',
        temp: '54.1 F (12.3 C)'
    },
    {
        name: 'Bend',
        forecastUrl: 'http://www.wunderground.com/US/OR/Bend.html',
        iconUrl: 'http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif',
        weather: 'Partly Cloudy',
        temp: '55.0 F (12.8 C)'
    },
    {
        name: 'Manzanita',
        forecastUrl: 'http://www.wunderground.com/US/OR/Manzanita.html',
        iconUrl: 'http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/rain.gif',
        weather: 'Light Rain',
        temp: '55.0 F (12.8 C)'
        }
    ]
};
}
```

I assign the returned object to `matrix` of `partials` in my application file as such:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
if (!res.locals.partials) res.locals.partials = {};  
res.locals.partials.matrix = getWeatherData();      
next();                                          
});
```

The partial file called weather2.handlebars:

```
<div class="weatherWidget">
{{#each partials.matrix.locations}}
    <div class="location">
        <h3>{{name}}</h3>
        <a href="{{forecastUrl}}">
            <img src="{{iconUrl}}" alt="{{weather}}">
            {{weather}}, {{temp}}
        </a>
    </div>
 {{/each}}
 <small>Source: <a href="http://www.wunderground.com">Weather
        Underground</a></small>
</div>
```

This goes onto the view home.handlebars:

```
<h1>Welcome to Meadowlark Travel</h1>
{{> weather2}}
```

And finally the main layout main.handlebars:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Meadowlark Travel</title>

</head>
<body>
    <header><img src="/img/cat.png" alt="Meadowlark Travel Logo"></header>
    {{{body}}}

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: heres the final output:

```
<html lang="en"><head>
     <script src="/vendor/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Meadowlark Travel</title>

</head>
<body>
    <header><img src="/img/cat.png" alt="Meadowlark Travel Logo"></header>
    <h1>Welcome to Meadowlark Travel</h1>
<div class="weatherWidget">

 <small>Source: <a href="http://www.wunderground.com">Weather
        Underground</a></small>
</div>




</body></html>
```

I'm also having trouble with getting sections to show up properly (similiar issue with partials) but I'll be asking that another day.

EDIT: some additional info: I'm using up to date express4 and handlebars + express3-handlebars
https://www.npmjs.org/package/express3-handlebars

Comment: I'm not familiar with express but you need to call `render` somewhere, right? Can you also share that part of code?

Comment: `render` loads the home.handlebars view onto the main layout. weather2.handlebars goes on this home view
    `app.get('/', function (req, res) { res.render('home'); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved the issue:

Define the middleware above all other middleware already defined in the app file (I was reminded why ordering of middleware in the code is very important thanks to this problem).